# MongoDB Mgo Sort Skip Limit Aggregation Pipeline - Results out of order

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, pipeline, mgo

I've got a document "item" that looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a146ce6cca59f21e897589b"),
"platform" : "example_platform",
"mp_id" : "example_marketplace_id",
"category" : {
    "platform" : "example_platform",
    "id" : 999,
    "name" : "example_category_name"
},
"image_urls" : [ 
"http://example.com/image.jpg"
],
"title" : "example_title",
"seller" : {
    "username" : "example_username",
    "platform" : "example_platform",
},
"quantity_sold" : 100,
"sales" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a146cf3cca59f21e8975951"),
        "time" : ISODate("2017-09-09T04:07:36.000Z"),
        "amount" : 31.4500007629395,
        "currency" : "USD",
        "buyer" : {
            "username" : "example_username",
            "platform" : "example_platform",
        },
        "item_id" : ObjectId("5a146ce6cca59f21e897589b")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a146cf3cca59f21e8975952"),
        "time" : ISODate("2017-11-16T01:24:10.000Z"),
        "amount" : 27.0900001525879,
        "currency" : "USD",
        "buyer" : {
            "username" : "example_username",
            "platform" : "example_platform",
        },
        "item_id" : ObjectId("5a146ce6cca59f21e897589b")
    }
]
```

}

What I'd like to do is be able to query to db to sort the items by number of times an item sold within a given time range, and also paginate through these results using skip and limit (or some other method).

This is what my aggregation query/pipeline currently looks like:

```
func (this SellerItemsQuery) MakePipeline() []bson.M{
    var pipeline = []bson.M{
        {"$match": bson.M{
            "seller.username": this.Username,
            "seller.platform": this.Platform,
        }}}
    if !this.SalesFromDate.Equal(time.Time{}) && !this.SalesToDate.Equal(time.Time{}) {
        pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{
            "$addFields": bson.M{
                "sales": bson.M{
                    "$filter": bson.M{
                        "input": "$sales",
                        "as":    "sale",
                        "cond":  bson.M{"$and": []bson.M{{"$gte": []interface{}{"$$sale.time", this.SalesFromDate}}, {"$lte": []interface{}{"$$sale.time", this.SalesToDate}}}},
                    },
                },
            },
        })
    }
    pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{
        "$addFields": bson.M{
            "num_sales": bson.M{
                "$size": bson.M{
                    "$ifNull": []interface{}{
                        "$sales", []interface{}{},
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })
    pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{
        "$sort": bson.M{"num_sales": -1,
                        "_id": 1},
    }, bson.M{
        "$skip": this.Skip,
    }, bson.M{
        "$limit": this.Limit,
    })
    return pipeline
```

The issue with this currently is that it returns very inconsistent results.  When paginating by 25 items at a time (skip=0&limit=25, skip=25&limit=25, etc.).  The first result set is usually correct, with the best selling items in given time period appearing at the top and number of sales decreasing as expected, however by the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th set of 25 the results are almost completely random.  Number of sales of items in the set will suddenly drop to zero, while the next set will include items with 3 sales, etc.  Completely out of order, with duplicate items showing up as well, even though I've included a sort by {_id: 1} in the pipeline, which I thought would solve this problem.

Comment: Which MongoDB version is this?

Comment: The thing that - I'm guessing - could be wrong here is your conditional $addFields stage which in some cases will render the sorting a little useless since the field that your sorting on has either zeros for all documents in case your ìf`statement returns false and otherwise some reasonable values. So You might want to check that `ìf` statement and make sure it behaves the way it should.

Comment: Version 3.4.10.  Double-checked the if statement and it works properly.  Also thought it might be because not all items have a sales array subdocument if they don't have any sales, so added an $ifNull to the "input" field same as the $addField for "num_sales" part of the pipeline.  Problem still persists

Comment: Your issue might be caused by different date formats in your documents. In the example you gave, there is this: `"time": "2017-11-06T15:13:43-06:00"` which appears not to be a proper date type but rather a string that cannot be compared using the comparison you have in your conditional `$addFields` stage. You want to store your dates as "real `Date`s". see this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: What might also cause confusion is that you appear to have an `id` field whereas you are sorting by the "_id" field...

Comment: Ah, no that's just how json encoder renders it. Should probably clarify that the above is json output, and "time" is definitely a real Date object. Same story with "id" field. In the db it's "_id", when rendered to json, it's "id".

Comment: Then please post what's really in the db since there is no way you'll get a clean answer otherwise.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Edited to include actual document as it appears in Robomongo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159644/discussion-between-dnickless-and-pornstache).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was that bson.M structs are unordered, so sometimes it would sort by "_id" field before sorting by "num_sales" field, which resulted in out of order result set.  Swtiched to using bson.D ordered pairs instead:

```
bson.M{
        "$sort": bson.M{"num_sales": -1,
                        "_id": 1},
    },
```

Became:

```
bson.M{
        "$sort": bson.D{{"num_sales", -1},
                {"_id", 1}},
    },
```